# Difficulty in writing crops of images using OpenCV and Python

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing

I am using the following code to read multiple images from a folder and to take a specific crop from all of them and also write them at the end. The cropping part does not seem to work meaning the cropped parts are not getting written.

```
# import the necessary packages
import cv2
import os, os.path


#image path and valid extensions
imageDir = "C:\\Users\\Sayak\\Desktop\\Training\\eye\\1" #specify your path here
image_path_list = []
valid_image_extensions = [".jpg", ".jpeg", ".png", ".tif", ".tiff"] #specify your vald extensions here
valid_image_extensions = [item.lower() for item in valid_image_extensions]

#create a list all files in directory and
#append files with a vaild extention to image_path_list
for file in os.listdir(imageDir):
    extension = os.path.splitext(file)[1]
    if extension.lower() not in valid_image_extensions:
        continue
    image_path_list.append(os.path.join(imageDir, file))

#loop through image_path_list to open each image
for imagePath in image_path_list:
    image = cv2.imread(imagePath)

    # display the image on screen with imshow()
    # after checking that it loaded
    if image is not None:
        cv2.imshow(imagePath, image)
    elif image is None:
        print ("Error loading: " + imagePath)
        #end this loop iteration and move on to next image
        continue
    crop_img = image[200:400, 100:300]
    cv2.imwrite('pic{:>05}.jpg'.format(imagePath), crop_img)

    # wait time in milliseconds
    # this is required to show the image
    # 0 = wait indefinitely
    # exit when escape key is pressed
    key = cv2.waitKey(0)
    if key == 27: # escape
        break
# close any open windows
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Comment: What is meant by `The cropping part does not seem to work`, is there any error ? or the cropped images are not written at all ?

Comment: Yes the cropped images are not written at all. Sorry for being unclear with that part. Post edited.

Comment: Then please review the path you are passing to `cv2.imwrite()` to see it is a valid path ?

Comment: It's a basic of debugging, isn't it, that if files arent being written it may be because either the file write is failing because of permissions or a dodgy filename, or the data to be written is bad. You have it all in your power to debug this: print the filename to check it is valid and that the path being written to has write permissions, or display the cropped image to make sure it is good. People should be taught debugging, not programming.

Comment: Permissions and filenames are checked. No problem with that.

Comment: Show us the exact path/filename that is being given to cv2.imwrite. And display the the cropped image, is it what you expect?

Comment: C:\Users\Sayak\Desktop\Training\eye\1\E_1  (1).jpg
C:\Users\Sayak\Desktop\Training\eye\1\E_1  (2).jpg
C:\Users\Sayak\Desktop\Training\eye\1\E_1  (3).jpg
C:\Users\Sayak\Desktop\Training\eye\1\E_1  (4).jpg
C:\Users\Sayak\Desktop\Training\eye\1\E_1  (5).jpg
C:\Users\Sayak\Desktop\Training\eye\1\E_1  (6).jpg
C:\Users\Sayak\Desktop\Training\eye\1\E_1  (7).jpg
C:\Users\Sayak\Desktop\Training\eye\1\E_1  (8).jpg

imagePath.

Answer (score 0):

I have modified your code posted above. The **problem lies with your string formatting** used **in cv2.imwrite()**. The **first argument must be an absolute path** to where the file should be saved, but your code is passing in something like this. 
pic{:>05}.jpg => pic/home/ubuntu/Downloads/10_page.png.jpg. When I used a valid file name there is no problem saving the cropped image at all.

```
#loop through image_path_list to open each image
for i,imagePath in enumerate(image_path_list):
    image = cv2.imread(imagePath)
    # display the image on screen with imshow()
    # after checking that it loaded
    if image is not None:
        cv2.imshow(imagePath, image)
    elif image is None:
        print ("Error loading: " + imagePath)
        #end this loop iteration and move on to next image
        continue
    # Please check if the size of original image is larger than the pixels you are trying to crop.
    (height, width, channels) = image.shape
    if height >= 400 and width >= 300:
        plt.imshow(image)
        plt.title('Original')
        plt.show()
        crop_img = image[100:400, 100:400]

        # Problem lies with this path. Ambiguous like pic/home/ubuntu/Downloads/10_page.png.jpg
        print('pic{:>05}.jpg'.format(imagePath))

        # Try a proper path. A dirname + file_name.extension as below, you will have no problem saving.
        new_image = os.path.join(imageDir,'{}.png'.format(str(i)))
        cv2.imwrite(new_image, crop_img)
        plt.imshow(crop_img)
        plt.title('Cropped')
        plt.show()
```